# Python OpenCV image interpolation inaccuracy

Tags: python, image, opencv, interpolation

I am familiar with using OpenCV through the Python interface, but while using the image interpolation facilities for a somewhat non-standard problem requiring a good deal of accuracy, I noticed some unexpected inaccuracy in the results.  The code below illustrates my issue.  Any ideas?  Am I just trying to use the interpolater outside of its design accuracy?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Source gradient image from 0 to 255
src = np.atleast_2d(np.linspace(0,255,10));

# Set up to interpolate from first pixel value to last pixel value
map_x_32 = np.linspace(0,9,101)
map_x_32 = np.atleast_2d(map_x_32).astype('float32')
map_y_32 = map_x_32*0

# Interpolate using OpenCV
output = cv2.remap(src, map_x_32, map_y_32, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

# Truth
output_truth = np.atleast_2d(np.linspace(0,255,101));

interp_error = output - output_truth

plt.plot(interp_error[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same inaccuracy. `scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates` is much more accurate, but in my case also 5x slower.

You could use it in this case as:

```
# Interpolate using Scipy
xy = np.vstack((map_y_32[np.newaxis,:,:], map_x_32[np.newaxis,:,:]))
output_scipy = scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates(src, xy, order=1)
```